# Laravel using own authentication method

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 5.2 and I m turning in circle. I read the doc on using my own authentication method and it is not clear at all...

What I did is the below:
Create a file in app/providers called myAuthServiceProvider.php with below code

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class MyAuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

  public function boot()
  {

    $this->registerPolicies();

    Auth::provider('myauth', function ($app) {
            // Return an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider...

            return new MyAuthServiceProvider($app->make('myauth.connection'));
        });

  }

  public function validateCredentials(UserInterface $user, array $credentials)
  {
    // we'll assume if a user was retrieved, it's good
    return true;
  }

}
```

Then in the auth.php located in the config folder, I change

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
```

to

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'myauth',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
```

Then I get a myauth is not defined.

Thanks if you can help.

Comment: I don't know the right answer, but what I can tell you is this: the driver is for the ORM that Laravel uses and needs to be eloquent. Model should be your class that will be used, you can either create or use/modify the default user class or create your own and replace it there

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?